# Using GPIO pin for reset

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, gpio, device-tree

I have a requirement where I need to pull down the GPIO for 5 milliseconds. The GPIO is connected to a chip reset pin. As per the requirement I need to reset the chip. To reset the chip we need to give 5 milliseconds low pulse on the reset pin. There is no driver for the chip. Can anyone guide me anywhere in the kernel source where a similar kind of requirement requirement was implemented or any inputs we can add this gpio number parsing from dts and delay to generate low pulse.

Comment: It's unclear what chip you are talking about, what reset pin is for: There is a crucial difference if you want to use GPIO to reset some system controller or chip itself. You need to work on your question more.